# relation on A defined by (a, b) ≈ (c, d) whenever ad = bc . What goes wrong with A when it includes 0

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Consider the equivalence relation A be a set of nonzero integers and let ≈ be the relation on A×A defined by
(a, b) ≈ (c, d) whenever ad = bc

1.What goes wrong with their solution, if we let A contain all integers
including zero?

2.We want the equivalence class [(a, b)] to represent the rational number
a/b. We would like to deﬁne the product of classes [(a, b)] and [(c, d)] as the class
[(a·c, b·d)]. However, we need to check that this operation is well-deﬁned. That is: assuming that (a, b) ≈ (a', b') and (c, d) ≈ (c', d'), you need to argue that (a · c, b · d) ≈ (a'· c', b'· d').

Comment: What goes wrong with what solution? You've just defined a relation. You haven't shown it is an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: what $(a,b)$ satisfies $(a,b)\approx (0,0)$?